# How to avoid Nil / nan in simple calculation

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I'm a very beginner in swift, and my learning project is to build a 'cross multiplication' calculator. But how do I avoid that incase of an impossible calculation the text label is giving the output NaN or the app crashes.

I thought it should be after the result that, the value of the output should be checkt to be valid - or what do i get wrong?
this doesn't work:

```
    if convert = false {
        output.text = "X"
    }
```

see full code below.

```
@IBOutlet weak var textField1: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var textField2: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var textField3: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var output: UILabel!

@IBAction func calculationMethod(_ sender: Any) {
    let textField1Double: Double? = Double(textField1.text!)
    let textField2Double: Double? = Double(textField2.text!)
    let textField3Double: Double? = Double(textField3.text!)

    let convert = textField3Double! * textField2Double! / textField1Double!

    if convert = false {
        output.text = "X"
    }

    let convertText = String(convert)

    output.text = convertText

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check if all the text fields contain `Double` values. If they do, you need to make sure the first text field isn't 0.

```
if let textField1Double = Double(textField1.text!),
   let textField2Double = Double(textField2.text!), 
   let textField3Double = Double(textField3.text!), 
   textField1Double != 0 {
    let result = textField3Double * textField2Double / textField1Double
    output.text = String(result)
} else {
    output.text = "X"
}
```

---

**Tip:** Since you seem to be new, look up [Optional Chaining](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/OptionalChaining.html) for a better understanding of the solution.

Comment: Great, this works! and I sort of understand it :) Thank you very much!

Comment: @fiebigc you can loop up optional chaining to better understand the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

As you can see the [text](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfield/1619635-text) object is an optional one, which means it could have a value or it could have a nil inside of it.

When you use the "bang" (exclamation mark) you are force unwrapping an optional (you are sure that it has a value thus, will never crash).

In order to avoid that just simply use conditional binding:

```
if let possibleValue = textField1.text {
  // you can now safely use the possibleValue
}
else {
  // There is no value inside the optional object
}
```

In addition, you can create an extension for `UITextField` that instead of writing `if let` each time you need just use a computed var for that:

```
extension UITextField {
 var doubleValue: Double {
   return textField1.text == nil ? 1 : Double(textField1.text)
 }
}
```

*Note*:

> This string is "" by default.

Of course, the code snip above is just an example and can easily be crashed so adjust for your own needs, Good luck

Comment: fyi `text` will never be nil. It will be "" if nothing is there.

Comment: You are correct but we can't tell whether it will get checked before viewDidLoad (from OP's side) but thanks for reminding, will update the answer

Comment: thank you for your prompt response! I will have to try it out for a while to really understand it...